# Error in python after 'import tensorflow': TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'syntax'

Tags: ubuntu, tensorflow

I installed TensorFlow on my Ubuntu 15.10 machine as instructed for CPU only:

```sh
$ pip install https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-0.5.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl
```

Then when I run the Python REPL and import tensorflow, I get:

```sh
$ python
Python 2.7.10 (default, Oct 14 2015, 16:09:02) 
[GCC 5.2.1 20151010] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow as tf
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/phil/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
   from tensorflow.python import *
  File "/home/phil/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from tensorflow.core.framework.graph_pb2 import *
  File "/home/phil/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/core/framework/graph_pb2.py", line 16, in <module>
    from tensorflow.core.framework import attr_value_pb2 as     tensorflow_dot_core_dot_framework_dot_attr__value__pb2
  File "/home/phil/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/core/framework/attr_value_pb2.py", line 16, in <module>
    from tensorflow.core.framework import tensor_pb2 as tensorflow_dot_core_dot_framework_dot_tensor__pb2
  File "/home/phil/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/core/framework/tensor_pb2.py", line 16, in <module>
    from tensorflow.core.framework import tensor_shape_pb2 as tensorflow_dot_core_dot_framework_dot_tensor__shape__pb2
  File "/home/phil/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/core/framework/tensor_shape_pb2.py", line 22, in <module>
    serialized_pb=_b('\n,tensorflow/core/framework/tensor_shape.proto \x12\ntensorflow\"d\n\x10TensorShapeProto\x12-\n\x03\x64im\x18\x02 \x03(\x0b\x32 .tensorflow.TensorShapeProto.Dim\x1a!\n\x03\x44im\x12\x0c\n\x04size\x18\x01 \x01(\x03\x12\x0c\n\x04name\x18\x02 \x01(\tb\x06proto3')
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'syntax'
```

I have the Ubuntu protobuf-compiler package installed and it's version 2.6.1-1.2

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Several users have reported issues that arise when an older version of protobuf is installed.

TensorFlow requires (and uses a copy of) protobuf-3.0.0a4. However it seems to be conflicting with your installed version (perhaps due to how the PYTHONPATH environment variable is configured on your system?). Can you try uninstalling the `python-protobuf` package if it is installed, and then seeing if TensorFlow starts correctly?

Some users have had success when using a virtualenv. For instructions on installing TensorFlow into a virtualenv, see [the getting started guide](http://tensorflow.org/get_started/os_setup.md#virtualenv-based_installation).

Comment: Ok, I had to 'pip uninstall protobuf' as well. Then I reinstalled tensorflow (via pip), restarted the REPL and it was good, thanks.

Comment: I additionally had to 'brew uninstall protobuf', on OS X.

Comment: I had mistakingly installed using brew.. I too had to do `brew uninstall protobuf`

Answer (score 29):

This [github comment](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/11#issuecomment-155153983) solved my problem.

In short, you'll need `protobuf>=3.0` installed to make tensorflow work.

First uninstall whichever `protobuf` you have, then `pip install 'protobuf>=3.0.0a3'`.

It's not just an issue for Ubuntu, Mac OS also has a similar issue.

Comment: Confirmed OSX has the same error, because the version in brew most people will install is still 2.6.1

Comment: This definitely fixes the problem on OS X 10.11.5.  `pip install protobuf` installs 2.6.1, which doesn't work of course.

Answer (score 24):

It worked for me:

```
pip uninstall protobuf
pip uninstall tensorflow
brew uninstall protobuf
pip install https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/tensorflow-0.5.0-py2-none-any.whl

import google.protobuf
>>> print google.protobuf.__version__
3.0.0a4
>>> import tensorflow
```

Comment: Thank you!! After trying for a couple of minutes this finally worked!

Answer (score 5):

I was having similar issue today. It was because I had **python 3.7** installed which is not compatible with tensorflow as of July 30 2018.
Downgrading to `3.6` fixed the issue. Posted [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51600158/issues-installing-tensorflow-on-mac#51603687) here if anyone is interested.

Following github issue was helpful when resolving this issue: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/17022

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error while running on the python version 2.7. But everything went fine when i ran it using **python version 3**.

Try the following commands on bash shell:

```
python3
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 17 2016, 17:05:23)
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux 
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow
>>> exit()
```

It worked for me.