# Python unable to import tensorflow to Mac OS X 10.8

Tags: python, macos, tensorflow

I am trying to install tensorflow on my mac air (specs: OSX 10.8.4, 4GB RAM). While tensorflow installs cleanly, as on the tensorflow.org page, and I am able to do $ source bin/activate to get a tensorflow prompt, I am not able to import the package in python. This is what I get:

```
    >>> import tensorflow
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.client.client_lib import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/client_lib.py", line 35, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.client.session import InteractiveSession
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 11, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow as tf_session
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow = swig_import_helper()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow', fp, pathname, description)
ImportError: dlopen(/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow.so, 2): Symbol not found: ___sincos_stret
  Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow.so
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow.so
```

I looked at the common problems section on tensorflow, as well as searched for the ImportError above but have had no luck so far. I wonder if this is a protobuf issue as referenced in  [Error in python after 'import tensorflow': TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'syntax'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33622842/error-in-python-after-import-tensorflow-typeerror-init-got-an-unexpect) .
Thanks in advance.

Comment: So if you wonder if it is protobuf, why haven't you tried to install the latest protobuf, also people had problems with six. Try to reinstall both of the packages.

Comment: Try creating a virtual environment and install tensor flow in it. You can also install some good shell like ipython and then import tensorflow.

Comment: http://tensorflow.org/get_started/os_setup.md#common_install_problems

Answer (score 4):

The issue appears to be that the binary distribution of TensorFlow is not compatible with Mac OS X 10.8. The relevant part of the error message is this one:

```
Symbol not found: ___sincos_stret
```

According to [various](https://github.com/pioneerspacesim/pioneer/issues/2610) [sources](http://sourceforge.net/p/librecad/bugs/455/), this is a known issue when using binaries compiled for a newer version of Mac OS X on 10.8 (Mavericks), because the symbol `___sincos_stret` is not defined in the standard libraries for that version of the OS.

To address this, you will need to (i) upgrade to Mac OS X 10.9 or later, (ii) follow the instructions to [install from source](http://tensorflow.org/get_started/os_setup.md#installing_from_sources), or (iii) use [Docker](http://tensorflow.org/get_started/os_setup.md#docker-based_installation).

Comment: Versionitis: "install from source" says "We recommend using homebrew to install the bazel ..."; homebrew says "bazel: OS X Yosemite or newer is required."

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue. I used docker toolbox and was able to run tensorflow. You can follow my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38020709/tensorflow-import-error-on-os-x-10-8-5-expected-in) and my solution.

Comment: Please do not post (links to) [duplicate answers](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/211726/206345). Instead,your question should be closed as a duplicate of this one - especially as your answer is essentially the same information provided here by [mrry](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33685174/1677912).