# Tensorflow import Error on OS X 10.8.5 Expected in

Tags: python, macos, tensorflow, deep-learning

I am trying to install tensorflow in my mac. I have anaconda python. I installed tensorflow using

```
 pip install -i https://pypi.anaconda.org/jjhelmus/simple tensorflow
```

I also tried all the option given in tensorflow installation guide.

When I am trying to import it is giving following error:

```
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/SummerREU/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow.so, 2): Symbol not found: ___sincos_stret
  Referenced from: /Users/SummerREU/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow.so
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
 in /Users/SummerREU/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow.so
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was resolved after I upgraded to OS X 10.11. OS X 10.8.5 do not is not compatable for tesorflow even if you try to build from source. It can only run in OS X 10.8 using [docker](https://www.docker.com/products/docker-toolbox).

For installation using docker please follow [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/get_started/os_setup.html#docker-installation) link.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with python default version for OS X you need to install python using brew or just download it and change path variable