# Docker can't start "Default" despite successful installation on OSX 10.8.5

Tags: python, docker, tensorflow

I'm trying to get Tensorflow to run on OSX 10.8.5. It can't run natively on 10.8.5 per the answer here: [Python unable to import tensorflow to Mac OS X 10.8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33644635/python-unable-to-import-tensorflow-to-mac-os-x-10-8?rq=1), which mentions using Docker as a solution.

However, after a successful installation of Docker Toolbox, I get the following output when trying to run "Docker Quickstart Terminal" in Applications for the first time:

```
Starting "default"...
(default) Check network to re-create if needed...
(default) Creating a new host-only adapter produced an error: /usr/local/bin/VBoxManage hostonlyif create failed:
(default) 0%...
(default) Progress state: NS_ERROR_FAILURE
(default) VBoxManage: error: Failed to create the host-only adapter
(default) VBoxManage: error: VBoxNetAdpCtl: Error while adding new interface: failed to open /dev/vboxnetctl: No such file or directory
(default) VBoxManage: error: Details: code NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005), component HostNetworkInterfaceWrap, interface IHostNetworkInterface
(default) VBoxManage: error: Context: "RTEXITCODE handleCreate(HandlerArg *)" at line 71 of file VBoxManageHostonly.cpp
(default) 
(default) This is a known VirtualBox bug. Let's try to recover anyway...
Error setting up host only network on machine start: The host-only adapter we just created is not visible. This is a well known VirtualBox bug. You might want to uninstall it and reinstall at least version 5.0.12 that is is supposed to fix this issue
Regenerate TLS machine certs?  Warning: this is irreversible. (y/n): Regenerating TLS certificates
Waiting for SSH to be available...
```

1) What can I do about this error message?

2) If nothing, is there any other way to get Tensorflow to run on OSX 10.8.5?

Comment: You could try manually installing or upgrading to the most recent version of VirtualBox. Not sure if that's what comes packed in Docker Toolbox.

Comment: @R0MANARMY Thank you and sorry for the late reply, I was trying a bunch of solutions for the last few days. I tried what you suggested but kept getting the same error. Ultimately I resorted to using Amazon Web Services and running it on there, which is a good compromise while I wait to buy a new computer.