# Tensorflow from source master gives a syntax error from import

Tags: tensorflow, python-3.5, ubuntu-16.04

I tried compiling tensorflow from sources (master) and follow the [tensorflow instructions](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/get_started/os_setup.html#create-the-pip-package-and-install) using `python3` instead of `python2` (and `pip` defaults to `pip3`). I can achieve all steps until testing the first model.

I noticed that the problem can be minimally reproduced by doing a simple `import tensorflow`. The error is as follows:

```
$ python3
Python 3.5.2 (default, Jul  5 2016, 12:43:10) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:108] successfully opened CUDA library libcublas.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:108] successfully opened CUDA library libcudnn.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:108] successfully opened CUDA library libcufft.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:108] successfully opened CUDA library libcuda.so.1 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:108] successfully opened CUDA library libcurand.so locally
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 65, in <module>
    import tensorflow.contrib as contrib
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/__init__.py", line 30, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib import learn
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/__init__.py", line 72, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn import estimators
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.estimators.autoencoder import TensorFlowDNNAutoencoder
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/autoencoder.py", line 25, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.estimators.base import TensorFlowBaseTransformer
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/base.py", line 34, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.estimators import estimator
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/estimator.py", line 39, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.learn_io import data_feeder
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/learn_io/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.learn_io.dask_io import extract_dask_data
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/learn_io/dask_io.py", line 26, in <module>
    import dask.dataframe as dd
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/dask/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .delayed import do, delayed, value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/dask/delayed.py", line 12, in <module>
    from . import base
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/dask/base.py", line 287, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pandas/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from pandas.compat.numpy import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pandas/compat/__init__.py", line 350, in <module>
    from dateutil import parser as _date_parser
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/dateutil/parser.py", line 158
    l.append("%s=%s" % (attr, `value`))
                              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

[Other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33622842/error-in-python-after-import-tensorflow-typeerror-init-got-an-unexpect) related to similar syntax problems are related to older versions of `protobuf`, however my version is 3

```
$ pip3 show protobuf
---
Metadata-Version: 2.0
Name: protobuf
Version: 3.0.0b2
Summary: Protocol Buffers
Home-page: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/
Author: protobuf@googlegroups.com
Author-email: protobuf@googlegroups.com
Installer: pip
License: New BSD License
Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages
Requires: six, setuptools
Classifiers:
  Programming Language :: Python
  Programming Language :: Python :: 2
  Programming Language :: Python :: 2.6
  Programming Language :: Python :: 2.7
  Programming Language :: Python :: 3
  Programming Language :: Python :: 3.3
  Programming Language :: Python :: 3.4
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like the installed `dateutil` package (which TensorFlow depends on via `dask` and `pandas`) is incompatible with Python 3, using backticks as a synonym for `repr()`, which was removed in 3.0. The particular line from `dateutil/parser.py` where the error occurs was [updated for Python 3](https://github.com/dateutil/dateutil/commit/ac37a80ce677025e03951091284feab1eadc0404) in 2011.

Try running the following command to upgrade `dateutil`:

```
$ pip3 install python-dateutil --upgrade
```