# Tensorflow failing to run wide and deep network tutorial

Tags: tensorflow, pip, anaconda, python-3.5

I succeeded in installing Tensorflow and run the convolutional.py example.
    However when i go to run the example [Wide and Deep net tutorial](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/g3doc/tutorials/wide/index.md), i get the following error

```
 % python wide_deep_tutorial.py                                                                                                                 
   Training data is downloaded to /tmp/tmpr3k3fwnc
   Test data is downloaded to /tmp/tmpzxhrdh00
   model directory = /tmp/tmpg_s1yutm
   WARNING:tensorflow:The default value of combiner will change from "sum" to "sqrtn" after 2016/11/01.
   WARNING:tensorflow:The default value of combiner will change from "sum" to "sqrtn" after 2016/11/01.
   WARNING:tensorflow:The default value of combiner will change from "sum" to "sqrtn" after 2016/11/01.
   WARNING:tensorflow:The default value of combiner will change from "sum" to "sqrtn" after 2016/11/01.
   WARNING:tensorflow:The default value of combiner will change from "sum" to "sqrtn" after 2016/11/01.
   WARNING:tensorflow:The default value of combiner will change from "sum" to "sqrtn" after 2016/11/01.
   WARNING:tensorflow:The default value of combiner will change from "sum" to "sqrtn" after 2016/11/01.
   WARNING:tensorflow:The default value of combiner will change from "sum" to "sqrtn" after 2016/11/01.
   WARNING:tensorflow:The default value of combiner will change from "sum" to "sqrtn" after 2016/11/01.
   WARNING:tensorflow:The default value of combiner will change from "mean" to "sqrtn" after 2016/11/01.
   WARNING:tensorflow:The default value of combiner will change from "mean" to "sqrtn" after 2016/11/01.
   WARNING:tensorflow:The default value of combiner will change from "mean" to "sqrtn" after 2016/11/01.
   WARNING:tensorflow:The default value of combiner will change from "mean" to "sqrtn" after 2016/11/01.
   WARNING:tensorflow:The default value of combiner will change from "mean" to "sqrtn" after 2016/11/01.
   WARNING:tensorflow:The default value of combiner will change from "mean" to "sqrtn" after 2016/11/01.
   WARNING:tensorflow:From    /home/eliethesaiyan/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/dnn_linear_combined.py:711 in fit.: calling BaseEstimator.fit (from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.estimators.estimator) with x is deprecated and will be removed after 2016-12-01.
    Instructions for updating:
    Estimator is decoupled from Scikit Learn interface by moving into
    separate class SKCompat. Arguments x, y and batch_size are only
    available in the SKCompat class, Estimator will only accept input_fn.
    Example conversion:
      est = Estimator(...) -> est = SKCompat(Estimator(...))
    WARNING:tensorflow:From /home/eliethesaiyan/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/dnn_linear_combined.py:711 in fit.: calling BaseEstimator.fit (from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.estimators.estimator) with y is deprecated and will be removed after 2016-12-01.
    Instructions for updating:
    Estimator is decoupled from Scikit Learn interface by moving into
    separate class SKCompat. Arguments x, y and batch_size are only
    available in the SKCompat class, Estimator will only accept input_fn.
    Example conversion:
      est = Estimator(...) -> est = SKCompat(Estimator(...))
    WARNING:tensorflow:From /home/eliethesaiyan/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/dnn_linear_combined.py:711 in fit.: calling BaseEstimator.fit (from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.estimators.estimator) with batch_size is deprecated and will be removed after 2016-12-01.
    Instructions for updating:
    Estimator is decoupled from Scikit Learn interface by moving into
    separate class SKCompat. Arguments x, y and batch_size are only
    available in the SKCompat class, Estimator will only accept input_fn.
    Example conversion:
      est = Estimator(...) -> est = SKCompat(Estimator(...))
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "wide_deep_tutorial.py", line 208, in <module>
        tf.app.run()
      File "/home/eliethesaiyan/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 43, in run
        sys.exit(main(sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))
      File "wide_deep_tutorial.py", line 204, in main
        train_and_eval()
      File "wide_deep_tutorial.py", line 197, in train_and_eval
        m.fit(input_fn=lambda: input_fn(df_train), steps=FLAGS.train_steps)
      File "/home/eliethesaiyan/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/dnn_linear_combined.py", line 711, in fit
        max_steps=max_steps)
      File "/home/eliethesaiyan/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/deprecation.py", line 191, in new_func
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/home/eliethesaiyan/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/estimator.py", line 355, in fit
        max_steps=max_steps)
      File "/home/eliethesaiyan/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/estimator.py", line 690, in _train_model
        features, labels = input_fn()
      File "wide_deep_tutorial.py", line 197, in <lambda>
        m.fit(input_fn=lambda: input_fn(df_train), steps=FLAGS.train_steps)
      File "wide_deep_tutorial.py", line 159, in input_fn
        for k in CATEGORICAL_COLUMNS}
      File "wide_deep_tutorial.py", line 159, in <dictcomp>
        for k in CATEGORICAL_COLUMNS}
    TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'dense_shape'
```

The most issue that were raised in a [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33622842/error-in-python-after-import-tensorflow-typeerror-init-got-an-unexpect) question,some suggested to uninstall protobuf and install it after installing tensorflow,but it did not help in my case,i would appreciate a lot if anyone could help.

Comment: Try replacing `dense_shape` with `shape`. I think it will be called `dense_shape` in a future version of the API.

Comment: It worked,i think if i was to use dense_shape i should have checked out from github directly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**TL;DR:** Make sure to run the version of `wide_n_deep_tutorial.py` that matches the installed version of TensorFlow. For example, you can download the [version from the `r0.12` branch](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r0.12/tensorflow/examples/learn/wide_n_deep_tutorial.py) if you have TensorFlow 0.12 installed.

The file `wide_n_deep_tutorial.py` was [recently changed](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/commit/056c0877adbc6ce21842f0bcdc6bb62e18f15a03) in master branch of TensorFlow, to reflect a change in the API (as kempy [points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41178979/tensorflow-failing-to-run-wide-and-deep-network-tutorial#comment69579627_41178979) in their comment, `tf.SparseTensor.shape` is becoming `tf.SparseTensor.dense_shape` in the *next* release).

Comment: You re right,it was version issue,i will watch out the next release