# Issues installing Tensorflow on mac

Tags: macos, tensorflow

I am following instructions from tensorflow website using [virtualenv](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_mac#installing_with_virtualenv) to install and having following issue when validating installation using `import tensorflow as tf` in python interactive shell.
Please note, I am running **Python 3.7**

[image]

Here are list of packages I have installed.
[image]

Can someone help?

I also tried to remove `protobuf` suggested by [stackoverflow issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33622842/error-in-python-after-import-tensorflow-typeerror-init-got-an-unexpect#51599907) using `pip uninstall protobuf`, but doesn't help.

Comment: Have you tried `pip3 uninstall protobuf`, `brew uninstall protobuf` and reinstalling TensorFlow as well?

Comment: Yes, have tried to uninstall protobuf and tensorflow multiple times but no luck. By default, when I install tensortflow protobuf is installed.
`pip3 install https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/cpu/tensorflow-1.9.0-py3-none-any.whl`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to resolve above issue after some research. It looks like, tensorflow is not compatible with **python 3.7** (as of July 30th 18) which is what I had installed on my computer . 
Following [github issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/17022) helped me resolved the issue.

I installed python **3.6.6** using pyenv and setup virtualenv. Here is what I did:

```
# Install python 3.3.6 and create virtualenv    
$ pyenv install 3.6.6
    $ pyenv virtualenv 3.6.6 tensorflow_image_recognition_3_6_6
    $ pyenv activate tensorflow_image_recognition_3_6_6

# update pip
    $ easy_install -U pip

#Install tensorflow
    $ pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow

# Test if tensorflow is installed properly
    # open python interactive shell
    $ python 
    import tensorflow as tf
    hello = tf.constant('Hello, TensorFlow!')
    sess = tf.Session()
    print(sess.run(hello))
```